# Java Playframework nested templates - argument passing

Tags: java, templates, playframework

Can you pass **specific, limited number of arguments** to a included,nested template ?

For example, in *ParentTemplate.html*, to do something like this (consider this as pseudocode :) :

```
#{include 'path/to/ChildTemplate.html' arg1: someArgInParentTemplate, arg2: someArgInParentTemplate2 /}
```

So that we can access only 2 separated variables for handling in child template named *arg1* and *arg2*.

I personally don't like that all parent template variables are accessible in child template. Also, variable names in parent and in included child templates must be same - that's not good for templates modularity imo, or am I missing something here?

Simple and productive FW though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of using an include, create a tag (see [this](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/templates#aCreatetagsa)) and you will be able to limit the parameters it can access.